# opencv decision tree regression, predict unseen responses?

Tags: opencv, regression, decision-tree

I am using opencv3 for Visual Studio 2017, coding in C++, on a surface pro (windows 10 64-bit).

I want to train a decision tree so that it can predict with regression. I need it to be able to predict in between responses which were not in the represented training set. For example, this code:

```
cv::Mat samples(6, 1, CV_32FC1);
samples.at<float>(0, 0) = 1.5;
samples.at<float>(1, 0) = 2.7;
samples.at<float>(2, 0) = 3.8;
samples.at<float>(3, 0) = 4.3;
samples.at<float>(4, 0) = 5.4;
samples.at<float>(5, 0) = 5.2;

cv::Mat responses = samples.clone();

cv::Mat samples2(5, 1, CV_32FC1);
samples2.at<float>(0, 0) = 1.8;
samples2.at<float>(1, 0) = 2.5;
samples2.at<float>(2, 0) = 3.6;
samples2.at<float>(3, 0) = 4.4;
samples2.at<float>(4, 0) = 5.3;

cv::Ptr< cv::ml::DTrees > model = cv::ml::DTrees::create();
model->setMinSampleCount(1);
model->setCVFolds(1);
model->setMaxDepth(10);
model->setRegressionAccuracy(.01f);

model->train(samples, cv::ml::ROW_SAMPLE, responses);

cv::Mat results;
model->predict(samples2, results);
for (int i = 0; i < results.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < results.cols; j++)
        cout << results.at<float>(i, j) << ", ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

The output is:

> 1.5
>
> 2.7
>
> 3.8
>
> 4.3
>
> 5.2

This is a simple identity problem, whatever the sample is that's what the response should be. However, from this example, it can only predict the responses it has seen. From my understanding, this is because each response leaf is a constant value. After a decision tree finishes, it lands on one of those leaves with a constant value.

**My question is, does anyone know of a way to manipulate a decision tree (preferably using OpenCV) so that it can predict responses outside of what it has seen? e.g. using interpolation and/or extrapolation.**

Comment: Decision trees should be able to handle any real values in a regression mode, since the splits are formulated as greater than or lesser than x. Either you made a mistake in building your model, or there is somethign fishy in OpenCV.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I can do regression fine (using floating point values as responses). My question was: My question is, does anyone know of a way to manipulate a decision tree (preferably using OpenCV) so that it can predict responses outside of what it has seen? E.g. using interpolaton and/or extrapolation. I edited my question to use the E.g. part.

Comment: If you are talking about a classifier predicting some data points that were not present in the training set because they are from a completely different search space, then no. No classifier can do this. And you probably don't want do manually edit the code, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I mean neural networks can output values between those in the training set. It's also possible to do some form of interpolation to reach values between those in the training set. I have a couple ideas but am curious what people have tried.